# postgres delete json from jsoncolumn

Tags: python, json, postgresql

im having a problem trying to remove key from my json column, i have this:

```
{
    "owner": {
    "name": "Antionio José Restepo",
    "phone": "4445567",
    "address": "Calle 45 # 34 - 22",
    "id_number": "78549378"
  },
  "score": 3.1,
  "company": "Taxi Individual",
  "taxi_drivers": {
    "71111111": {
      "name": "Juan Carlos Saldarriaga",
      "image": ".jpg",
      "identification": "71111111"
    },
    "1231230123": {
      "name": "mariana",
      "image": ".jpg",
      "identification": "1231230123"
    },
    "0998922": {
      "name": "Marinian",
      "image": ".jpg",
      "identification": "0998922"
    }
  },
  "active_driver": "71111111",
  "company_phone": "0346069888",
  "card_operation": true,
  "car_registration": "TSJ230",
  "insurance_accidents": true,
  "mechanical_revision": false
}
```

and i what to delete "71111111" in "taxi_drivers" position, im doing this:

```
UPDATE products 
SET description = description::jsonb #- '{taxi_drivers,71111111}' 
WHERE  uid = 'row_id'
```

but isnt working, python says that i have some sql error syntaxis:
ERROR:  error de sintaxis en o cerca de «71111111»
LINE 2: ...scription = description::jsonb #- '{taxi_drivers,'71111111'}...

i need some another option to erase that position, someona can help me?

Comment: To clarify, you aren't trying to delete the key "taxi_drivers" - just set the value to NULL?

Comment: no, i'm trying to delete the key "71111111" in taxi_drivers